# padrino: command not found

Tags: rubygems, padrino

I successfully installed Padrino with `sudo gem install padrino`, but when I try and run `padrino ...`, I get `-bash: padrino: command not found`. Even `sudo` produces this result. Anyone else run into this problem? I looked in `/usr/bin`, but it is not there. Thank you for your help.

I am using Mac OS X.6.8. I have been successfully installing and using gems all day, until now.

Comment: Did `gem` tell you where the binaries went?

Comment: As far as I can tell, padrino gem doesn't have any binaries.

Comment: @nneonneo No, just that 1 gem was successfully installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, fixed it. After looking at `gem environment`'s output, I noticed that the path listed as EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY was not in my `PATH`. Adding it to my `.bashrc` solved the problem.

Comment: That was exactly my problem too. I'm surprised that RVM doesn't add it as part of the install...

Answer (score 2):

Can you try:

```
sudo gem update --system
gem search padrino --no-version | xargs sudo gem uninstall -a
```

then

```
sudo gem install padrino
```

then

```
which padrino
which padrino-gen
```

Are you using rvm or rbenv?

Comment: Still nothing. The first command successfully uninstalls all, and the second successfully reinstalls the 7 gems, but the `which` commands still produce nothing.

Comment: Also, using neither rvm nor rbenv.

Answer (score 1):

I face the same situtation and terminal restart solved my issue.
I use *rbenv* as a version manager. Even though *padrino* was in the gems folder, the command itself was unreachable.

After I restarted my terminal, the newly installed gem was available.